# Django on production server (No module named urls)

Tags: django, django-urls, production-environment, django-settings, dev-to-production

I'm setting Django on production server and have this strange error(on picture below)
As you can see pythonpath seems to be ok(first row is my project folder), I definitely have module urls.py inside my project/project folder, I have **init** file there and my ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'(I also tried without project name, but it didn't help either).
So, that is strange why it can't find it :(
I have to say that I tried to create a new project on server and then it seems to be ok, but with this project that is copied from local server it is behaving like this.

Printscreen of error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I can think of is the process of package creation. What process have you followed to deploy your Django application?

If you have compiled the Django application on your local machine or CI server and then deployed the compiled package then you will run into Import module issues because pyc files will contain hard coded paths of your local machine or CI servers. To fix it before compiling the python files you should create the same hierarchy on your local/CI server and then compile and deploy.

Hope this helps.

**[Edit]**

I agree hardcoded paths in pyc files is PITA and we have been doing this in our production environment once we discovered it.

However I do not agree with you to re generate pyc files on the server because as your application will grow and you move towards a large application it will become very slow.

You don't have to keep your development environment directory to follow production directory structure. Instead you can have any directory path on development machine and create a separate bash script which will create a package for you by creating a directory structure that you follow on production. Bash script will have the logic of

- Creating a directory structure similar to production
- Checking out the code from source control
- Compile the code using `python -m compileall .`
- Create a tarball

You can untar this tarball on production server and your application should run fine.

For more information about package creation in python and best practices, [check out this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uza3AMUOESk)

Comment: Is there a way to regenerate pyc files on the server? And if not, do you mean that I can just have same directories names on my local machine and the reupload it and it should work? Just directories or something else too?

Comment: 1. Yes there is a way to generate pyc files on the server but it is not recommended for production applications. Just because for multiple servers it will increase the time for deployment.
2. Yes create the same directory structure on your local machine like `/opt/myenv/app` and run the compile command and then deploy the compiled output on production.

Comment: Ok, I will try to make same hierarchy on local PC and upload to server, I will post later if it works :)

Comment: Yes, it seems like pyc files are important for that stuff... this is actually the pain in the ass, because it dictates you where you need to make you development directory, I personally would better re-generate pyc files once I update info on server, rather tying my local PC and server in such a manner. Can you point me how to do that stuff with pyc recompilation? at least what do I need to google for :)

Comment: I have added more information to answer your queries.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your project is in your path, actually. The traceback is only showing Django packages.